# Program is executing but AT commands not showing in serial monitor

Tags: arduino, gsm, at-command, serial-communication, sim800l

My purpose was to send SMS using [GSM SIM800L coreboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daxN0.jpg)  and Arduino UNO. Here is the code

```
    #include <SoftwareSerial.h>

//Create a software serial object to communicate with SIM800L
SoftwareSerial mySerial(3, 2); //SIM800L Tx & Rx is connected to Arduino #3 & #2

void setup()
{
  //Begin serial communication with Arduino and Arduino IDE (Serial Monitor)
  Serial.begin(115200);

  //Begin serial communication with Arduino and SIM800L
  mySerial.begin(115200);

  Serial.println("Initializing..."); 
  delay(1000);

  mySerial.println("AT"); //Once the handshake test is successful, it will back to OK
  updateSerial();

  mySerial.println("AT+CMGF=1"); // Configuring TEXT mode
  updateSerial();
  mySerial.println("AT+CMGS=\"+ZZxxxxxxxxx\"");//change ZZ with country code and xxxxxxxxxxx with phone number to sms
  updateSerial();
  mySerial.print("TEST"); //text content
  updateSerial();
  mySerial.write(26);
}

void loop()
{
}

void updateSerial()
{
  delay(500);
  while (Serial.available()) 
  {
    mySerial.write(Serial.read());//Forward what Serial received to Software Serial Port
  }
  while(mySerial.available()) 
  {
    Serial.write(mySerial.read());//Forward what Software Serial received to Serial Port
  }
}
```

And here is the serial monitor output

```
 22:31:19.430 -> Initializing...
```

However, when I run the code, I get the text message to my mobile phone, but [I can't see any AT commands in the serial monitor. It only outputs "Initializing..."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOSR7.png) .
All the connections and baud rates are okay, checked a thousand times. Has connected 2A, 4.4v power supply to the GSM coreboard and shorten the wires, and sho No bad soldering joints. GSM module red led flash per 3 seconds. And again, I'm getting the text message to my phone. So that means the problem is with the Arduino serial monitor or code, not in the hardware. I need to see AT commands because I need to put more commands through the serial monitor, I tried typing and click send, But it's not showing anything. Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're sending AT-commands through another serial connection.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Yes, I'm using another serial communication, But both should show in the same serial monitor, Because Every youtube video and forum I see, they send commands through the same serial monitor which use to print normal things. here is an example video I followed [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mw7ocaGKsXs)

Comment: You will see the AT commands, but only if the device you're sending to has echo enabled.  Try sending "ATE1'" to your device to enable echo.

Comment: SoftwareSerial in Arduino Uno doesn't support 115200 bade rate and use  while (Serial.available())  and  while(mySerial.available())  in loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is reversed in the `updateSerial()` function.

Actually, you are sending the `AT` command over `mySerial` at the `setup` function, then you need to wait for the answer to come in that object `mySerial`.

So, you should do the `while (!mySerial.available()) ;` to be able to read something from it. Once this loop ends, you can read from `mySerial`.

However, you want to forward it to the serial monitor so, you also need to check if the `Serial` is available to be written to, that is why you also waits for it, resulting in the `while (!mySerial.available() || !Serial.available()) ;`.

Once you are sure both serials are available, you can read from one and write what you just read into the other one: `Serial.Write(mySerial.read())`.

Also, I do not see any need for the `mySerial.write(Serial.read())` call, because the `Serial` is being used just to forward what you are receiving from the SIM800L, thus, you could simply remove that part.

Thus, the correction of your function would result in this:

```c
void updateSerial()
{
    delay(500);
    while (!mySerial.available() || !Serial.available())
        ;

    Serial.write(mySerial.read());
}
```

So, with this, everything you receive from the SIM800L is forwarded to the serial monitor.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer, however, It still same as before. I buy a new Arduino Uno and a new gsm module, but it is the same as before, only show initializing in the output.